# Width auto com o segundo elemento preenchendo o espaço restante

Tags: css

Tenho o código abaixo:

```css
.segura{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.label{
  width: 90px;
  height: 20px;;
  float: left;
  background-color: #6fccdd;
}
.campo{
  width: calc(100% - 90px);
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #999999;
  border: solid 0px transparent;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="segura">
  <label class="label">nome</label>
  <input value="" type="text" class="campo">
</div>
```

Se eu definir uma largura para o LABEL, funciona, mas como fazer o mesmo efeito, colocando width: auto; para o LABEL e o CAMPO preencher todo o espaço restante?

Comment: Cara não dei para entender o que vc quer fazer... o label já tem um tamanho e o input já ocupa o restante.... o que vc está pretendendo fazer, ou qual comportamento quer fazer com relação a largura, isso não ficou claro

Comment: Ja responderam o que eu precisava, mas respondendo a sua dúvida: eu quero poder colocar width: auto; no label, pq cada label vai ter uma palavra diferente (nome, e-mail, mensagem, etc..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: flex` na div principal e coloque `flex: 1` no campo. Veja que eliminei algumas propriedades, como o `float: left` e o `width` do campo e da label. O `flex: 1` faz com que o elemento ocupe o restante da área. Colocar `display: block` na div também é redundante, porque as divs já são `block`. Também não precisa colocar `width: auto`, porque o `width` já é `auto` por padrão. Basta omiti-lo. Colocar `width: 100%` também não precisa, porque a div já ocupa 100% da largura. Veja:

```css
.segura{
  /*width: 100%;*/
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.label{
  /*width: 90px;*/
  height: 20px;;
  /*float: left;*/
  background-color: #6fccdd;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.campo{
  /*width: calc(100% - 90px);*/
  height: 20px;
  /*float: left;*/
  background-color: #999999;
  border: solid 0px transparent;
  padding: 0px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="segura">
  <label class="label">nome</label>
  <input value="" type="text" class="campo">
</div>
<div class="segura">
  <label class="label">endereço</label>
  <input value="" type="text" class="campo">
</div>
```